# Is there a way to express variables with a range of numbers to meet a loop condition in vba

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to express variable f as a range of numbers like for instance, f = 4 to 9 in excel vba? Because my intention here is to create a condition such that for i = 1 to lastColumn, if i falls into the range 4 to 9, as such it will scan through values from i to lastcolumn and accept headers(voltage,power and time) that lies within from cells(1,4) to cells(1,9) and after that the private sub voltagepowertime will be called where it creates multiple pivottables by using the columns of voltage, power and time when their headers are being detected at the first row.  I will also be grateful if there are others way to express my intention here.

[image]

```
 Dim sh as Worksheet

Dim LastColumn as integer

Dim f as integer

f=4 to 9 '------>How to express f as a range of number?

For i = 1 to LastColumn

if i = f Then

if sht.Cells(1,f).Value = "Voltage" And sht.Cells(1,f).Value= "Power" and sht.Cells(1,f).Value= "Time" Then

Call voltagepowertime
```

Comment: Make an `IF` inside the loop,   `IF i>=4 and I=<9 Then etc. etc.`

Comment: I am not sure I understand your „intention”... Can you better clarify what 4 to 9 wants to mean? Do you mean an array from 4 to 9? Do you mean something less then 4 and bigger then 9? And how to use such a strange type variable in `Cells(1, f)`? Can you better explain (in words) what is your need?

Comment: @FaneDuru sorry if sounds vague for my post. What I mean is that f is an integer that can range from 4 to 9 like f can be more than 4 but less than the value 9.

Comment: What columns in the range would you like to condition in this way?  "from i to lastcolumn", or to last row?

Comment: so my need is here is as i loops from 1 to lastcolumn, if i =f where i =4,5,6,7,8,9, the the entire values column is being extracted

Comment: @FaneDuru from i to lastcolumn in this case...

Comment: Can `i` be 4.3? And if you goes up to the last column, in which row will you want to make this checkings?

Comment: oh yeah i is an integer here so it cant be 4.3

Comment: Do you mean to check in columns 4,5,6,7,8,9?

Comment: @FaneDuru in that sense yes

Comment: Now I understood where to look for, but what to check in those columns?

Comment: @FaneDuru if that columns has voltage power or time as the header in the 1st row then the entire column of these header will be extracted

Comment: @FaneDuru extracted in the sense it will use these values in my private sub voltagepowertime to create multiple pivot tables

Comment: @cena: Look at my answer, please! Now it selects the columns having the header you wish. Would you like to select all of them at once (and you will do something with them in this combined way)? Why do you need to iterate between all existing columns if you need only that area? |Is it something you did not tell us?

Comment: @FaneDuru yeah i would like to select the entire column all at once. It is possible not to iterate between all existing columns?(sorry i didn't noticed that i unintentionally doing it). My question is more towards finding the 1st row that has the header voltage power or time. Is there still a way to do it?

Comment: @FaneDuru and if the 1st row has voltage power or time it will call a private sub call voltagepowertime

Comment: @FaneDuru is it possible to use the find function in this case?

Comment: @cena: You can use `Match` like this: `Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Match("Voltage", Range("A1:I1"))`. But, was my answer what you were looking for?

Comment: @cena: In case of `Match` function you must take care. If it does not find a match, it will return an error. This aspect can be controlled using a different function...

Comment: @FaneDuru yeah your advice is kinda helpful like I shouldn't try to iterate between all existing columns and should use something like find or match function instead I think?

Comment: @cena: So, do it in the way you like it! I also could see a duplicate question containing the same issue...

Comment: @cena: I've just posted another answer answering the question in the new way of asking... Please confirm that it matches your need.

Comment: @FaneDuru hi the answer you gave is not the main issue tho but I should be blamed for my poor explanation because there are some technical terms in VBA im not familiarise with. Nevertheless, thanks for your time and effort. Really appreciate it

Comment: But what were your expectations, as I could understand them, which could not be fulfilled by the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Like Daghan suggested you can easily achieve what you want with an If condition inside your loop that tests if the number is between 4 and 9.

Your coude would look more like this:

```
Dim sh as Worksheet
Dim LastColumn as integer

For i = 1 to LastColumn

  'You can easily change these numbers to fit whatever range you want
  if i >= 4 And i =< 9 Then

     if sht.Cells(1,i).Value = "Voltage" And sht.Cells(1,i).Value= "Power" and sht.Cells(1,i).Value= "Time" Then

        Call voltagepowertime

     End if

  End if
Next
```

Comment: thanks for the answers but may i check with you, the f in sht.cells(1,f).value should be replaced by i in this case?

Comment: That's right, sorry! 
Since that's what you're looking for specifically, whatever "i" passes the if test will be what you want to test on your second if. 
I edited the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub testExtraction()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, i As Long
   Set sh = ActiveSheet ' use here your sheet

   For i = 4 To 9
    If sh.Cells(1, i).Value = "Voltage" Or _
          sh.Cells(1, i).Value = "Power" Or _
          sh.Cells(1, i).Value = "Time" Then
         '"extract" your column. I did not understand what this extraction means...
         sh.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Select: Stop
    End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

I do not know what do you mean by 'extraction'. Now, the code stops after selecting of the column having the right header...

Answer (score 1):

This should answer your second question/approach...

```
Sub testMatch()
Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, voltPos As Long
 Set sh = ActiveSheet ' use please your sheet here
 Set rng = sh.Range("A1:I1")
 voltPos = IsMatch(rng, "Voltage")
 If voltPos <> 0 Then
    sh.Cells(1, voltPos).EntireColumn.Select
    'Call voltagepowertime 'You must know what this sub must do...
 Else
    MsgBox "Your string could not be found in the range..."
 End If
End Sub
Private Function IsMatch(rng As Range, strS As String) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    IsMatch = WorksheetFunction.Match(strS, rng)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
        IsMatch = 0
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

You can similarly use it for the rest of your strings...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution if there were to be a larger range of numbers but you could use a `select case`.

```
select case i
    case 4,5,6,7,8,9
        'do something
    case else
        'do something else
end select
```

Comment: hey thanks for the suggestion but Im afraid it would be problematic because my actual programme needs to run a huge number of columns so using case might be very tedious